# VeeValidate, Vuetify | TypeError: compute is not a function

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vee-validate

I'm having an issue with login form validation using VeeValidate & Vuetify and don't have idea what's wrong. I have also Vuex set up and working if it matters. I tried to use many VeeValidate & Vuetify example forms but always ended with this error:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: compute is not a function"

found in

---> <ValidationProvider>
```

My code: https://pastebin.com/EC5cVriq

Comment: Pleaser not that all posts must be self-contained. While they may include external links, they cannot rely on them. Please review topics in the [help](https://StackOverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section for more info. All code, data, and error messages must be embedded in the post as text. Also see the topic on minimum viable examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed line

```
setInteractionMode('edger')
```

and passed interaction mode as a prop to ValidationObserver like this

```
<ValidationObserver
    ref="obs"
    v-slot="{ invalid, validated, handleSubmit }"
    mode="eager"
>
```

and it's working now.